# Change properties in manifest.json file on build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, manifest, netlify

I have a website with 2 domains like Page1.com and Page2.com. In my manifest.json file i have set the name to Page 1, but when the website is build and published to Page1.com and to Page2.com i want to change the name to be the same as the domain name. But how can i do this in my build step? Today i se Page 1 when i visit Page2.com.

I have tried to change the meta, application-name in my code to get the correct name, but this don't work.

My vue.config

```
const manifestJSON = require('./public/manifest.json')


module.exports = {
pluginOptions: {
i18n: {
  locale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  localeDir: 'locales',
  enableInSFC: true
}
},

runtimeCompiler: true,

pwa: {
themeColor: manifestJSON.theme_color,
name: manifestJSON.short_name,
msTileColor: manifestJSON.background_color,
appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
workboxOptions: {
  swSrc: 'service-worker.js',
  exclude: [
    /_redirects$/
  ]
}
}
```

}

This site is build with VueJs and use Netlify as host.

Comment: Hi there! So here you want a value to be different, but I don't see any condition under which the value would change. You said the manifest.json file has the name "Page 1" so it's always going to be "Page 1". How is your manifest.json file generated?

Comment: I only have a manifest.json file in my public folder. I think this was generated when i installed, cli-plugin-pwa.

Comment: Oh I see - then no, I would think that manifest file is generated every time you re-build. I'll clarify things in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the manifest file is generated by vue-cli every time you build your app. So you shouldn't be using it to seed the vue-config file.

The one file that you could use the way you have shown here would be your package.json file - but it won't hold the values you are looking for.

Your Vue.config file is where you would enter, manually, the pwa info like theme and background color, etc.

To get back to your initial question, you could create two separate build scripts in your package.json, one for page1 and one for page2, and use environment variables to specify the name you ant to use:

```
"scripts": {
    "page1": "env SITE_NAME='Page 1' npm run prod",
    "page2": "env SITE_NAME='Page 2' npm run prod",
    ...
}
```

Then in your vue.config file, you can use the variable to build your pwa object:

```
pwa: {
    name: process.env.SITE_NAME,
    ...
}
```

Finally, you can build your apps by calling

```
npm run page1
```

Be careful though: every build will overwrite your public folder! Depending on your context, how/when you build each app, you may have to take additional steps to generate two separate output folders.

Comment: Thanx. But i dont think my manifest file is generated on each build. If i change a value its still there?

Comment: How are you building your site? Or better yet, what are the scripts in your package.json file? The manifest _should_ be re-generated for production builds, I'm fairly certain.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. My manifest file is generated in my dist folder. I created a Environment Variable so now i can set the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `process.argv` to get a command line argument.

For example if you command to run the file is:

```
node file.js
```

Then using:

```
node file.js env_variable_str
```

Will have `process.argv[process.argv.length - 1] === "env_variable_str"`

In my case the manifest had to change not just the value but **also add/remove** a key depending on the argument. So I made a template (`manifest_template.json`) and used a "build helper" to create the correct manifest based on my argument in the `public/` folder. Then I chained this command with `npm run build` and had another chaining command which made the zip folder.

My workflow: `create manifest.json in public -> npm run build -> make zip with correct name`

Let me know if you want to see the code!